# Having trouble understanding why the class is being replaced on different index

Tags: javascript

I have a question from w3school filter example.

This is the code.
`current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(' active, "");`

I understand the active class is being replaced by empty string.
But what I don't understand is this is for index 0 and only that will be replaced. How come when the other buttons are clicked, the active class changed to empty string? When you click index 1, it now has active class to it and that's fine since `this.className += " active"` will add the active to whichever button is clicked.

Now you click index 2, how come index 1 is replaced with empty string or why active disappear and move to index 2? Isn't `current[0].className` fixed to only index 0? If somebody can explain this to me, that would be great.

Link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_elements

Comment: `current[0]` is coming from `document.getElementsByClassName("active")` which returns an array. Since there is only one element with `active` class at a time (it can be any of the buttons), the code can always refer to `current[0]`.

Comment: Also I'd recommend to use a [more modern API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for class manipulation instead of all that string splitting/joining trouble.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that current return an array. I missed that part. But then I am still confused about the current[0].className. I am not sure what is happening behind the hood. Modern API would probably make this a lot easier to comprehend but I still want to understand it. If you can explain what's happening after you click 3rd button and the highlight is on 2nd. I apologize if I am repeating myself.

Comment: @MoshFeu - NVM on my previous comment. I figured it out. So no matter which button has the active class, current[0].className will only work on one of them. I try changing to current[1].className and it doesn't work. Probably because there is only ONE active class name and array only return one which is index 0. Thank you for opening my mind.

Comment: Sure :) I repeat on @x1n13y84issmd42's comment. Do yourself a favor and don't learn from old examples. Learn the new (not that new already) API, to have an easier life.

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

There is for loop here so the event is added for each button. The `current` variable is an array of all elements with `"active"` class, and in the array there is always only one item (because there is only one element with this class), so you have to select the item with 0 index (`current[0]`).

And I think that better solution here will be just using `document.getElementByClassName("active");` (single element) so you don't have to care about one item array.